# WordPress: cleaning media library

Tags: plugins, media

I'm giving my website a clearout whilst I redesign it, and thought I'd delete a bunch of old images from the media library (about 50 or so).

I thought this would free up a lot of space, but now I see they are all still in my `/uploads` folder. I imagine this is due to me having multiple sizes of the same images.

Now these images are no longer recognised in my media library, is there any way to scan what is in the folder and remove those that aren't linked to any posts?

Comment: What about querying database for all images (media library) and copy to a spreadsheet and doing a VLOOKUP against a list of files in your `/uploads/*` directory?

Comment: The fastest way is to use a file manager or ftp and manually delete them.

Comment: @shanebp - that just deletes the files. Doesn't necessarily delete the item from Media. And there is the worry about removing images that are used in posts. There are plugins that will help with syncing media files to the Media page.

Comment: Thanks Rick, for clarifying.